# Facebook app to post as a page

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook Page with some friend, our fans send us texts we have to post on our page.

At the moment we are using a Google Form, it's good but copy paste is very boring...

So I coded a little website where our fans could post texts and with an administration interface, we can validate them and it post it automatically on our Facebook Page (as the page).

I requested these permissions : `'manage_pages'`, `'publish_pages'` (No problem)

But when I click to validate a text and post it as a page I have this error : 
**"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"**

My code :

```
public function update($id, UpdatePostRequest $request, LaravelFacebookSdk $fb)
{
    $post = $this->postRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

    if (empty($post)) {
        Flash::error('Askip non trouvé');

        return redirect(route('posts.index'));
    }

    $post = $this->postRepository->update($request->all(), $id);

    Flash::success('Mis à jour avec succès.');

    $user = User::find(Auth::id());
    if($request['state']) {

        $fb->post('/AskipNamur/feed', ['message' => 'test'], $user->fb);
    }

    //return redirect(route('posts.index'));
}
```

`$user->fb` is my access token

I read that I have to publish our Facebook app in order to post as a Page, I tried but I had this response :

> You don’t need any extended permissions for an app that you admin. App admins, and any account listed as a ‘role’ in the App Settings page, can access the permissions without submitting for review. 
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/security
>   You only need to submit for review if the users/customers of your app are using the permissions to enhance their experience in-app

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and LaravelFacebookSDK ( https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need login review, all permissions work without review for everyone with a role in the app.

The error message means that you either did not authorize `publish_pages` or that you are not using a **Page Token**. Debug the Access Token: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

About Tokens in general and how to generate the different ones:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/